# How to fetch the label text from string using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to fetch the text of checkbox label in the given code:

```
<label id="age_global_2" class="checked">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3016" name="age_global">
  2 - 3 Years
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

in jquery use

```
alert($.trim($('#age_global_2').text()));
```

Comment: alert($('#age_global_2').text());

Comment: I want to get it from class checked instead of id.

Comment: `alert($.trim($('.checked').text()));
`

Comment: `$('label.checked').text()` Faster.

Comment: but when i click on first check box it gives null & when i click on second check box it gives the result of first check box.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`$('#age_global_2').text();`